SwiftUI crash — Trying to pop to a missing destination
I have a simple main app architecture:
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var isSignedIn = false
@AppStorage("onboardingCompleted") var onboardingCompleted: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    Group {
        if onboardingCompleted && isSignedIn {
            MainView()
        } else {
            OnboardingView()
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        signIn()
    }
}

OnboardingView is a NavigationView. MainView is a TabView. I switch between these when the user finishes onboarding. However, as the user taps on the finish button in the last onboarding step, this gets written to the console:
Trying to pop to a missing destination - SwiftUI/NavigationBridge_PhoneTV.swift:213 - please file a bug report.

In production, this causes a crash. I looked around and it seems it is an issue when you embed TabView inside NavigationView or vice versa? But here it's not the case, they are standalone and I switch between them.
Any thoughts?

Can you include a [mre]?

Does this answer your question? SwiftUI NavigationView trying to pop to missing destination (Monoceros?)
